# Network invocations underlying OpenAI execution?

Tags: generative-models, gpt

Really a pretty basic question about generative models, but I'm trying to map my (limited) understanding of NNs generally to what's going on when I invoke an OpenAI API:

1. When the OpenAI [API docs](https://platform.openai.com/docs/models/models) state a limit to the prompt size for a model ("max tokens", which I assume is the same as what's also referred to as in the documentation as "context length"), does
   that correspond to the size of the input layer of the actual network implementing the model?
2. Does each token generated by invocation of the API correspond to an execution of the underlying model, presumably truncating the front of the original supplied prompt if prompt plus output has exceeded max tokens?